# Text and background color into a table

Tags: css, html-table, colors

I have a table and I want that the content of a cell and its background changes the color when the mouse hovers on it. So I have tried the following CSS

```css
td {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table width="150px">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="www.testing.com">testing</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It seems simple, but it doesn't work. The background change its color, while the text not.

Where is my fault? How can I correct?

Comment: please provide your html code.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9tb2L1q0/ please can you edit your qiuestion with a [mcve] demonstrating your problem as you may have other styles conflicting with the above ones

Comment: It's might be cdn issue. check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1cs4mk8r/)

Comment: Add your html too

Comment: @Pete The text into the cell is a link: here http://jsfiddle.net/9tb2L1q0/3/ there's an example of the problem.

Trying with a:hover is not good (http://jsfiddle.net/9tb2L1q0/4/) as the string become white only if it is exactly hovered.

The aim is to have a cell containing a link that prettily change the color when the mouse hover on the cell, not necessarily the link.

Comment: ok see my answer - you can target links in a cell that is hovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, links usually have their own hover style applied so you need to target the links in the table to change their colour:

```css
td {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

td:hover a {     /* only target links in a td cell that is hovered */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table width="150px">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="www.testing.com">testing</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted css is not incorrect, but maybe it gets overridden by something else. Try adding important to see if this is the case:

Also could you post your html as well?

```css
 td {
     background-color: white !important;
     color: black !important;
     }
  td:hover {
     background-color: black !important;
     color: white !important;
     }
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```